# Use pandas to plot highest correlations

Tags: pandas, correlation

I have been plotting correlations via heatmaps with the following code. However, there are too many variables. Is it possible to plot the highest correlations ( over .5 and -.5) on a graph?

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [80,80]
corr3 = datasetcm.corr()


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(corr3,cmap='coolwarm', vmin=-1, vmax=1)
fig.colorbar(cax)
ticks = np.arange(0,len(datasetcm.columns),1)
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(datasetcm.columns)
ax.set_yticklabels(datasetcm.columns)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter your correlation matrix on the treshold of 0.5 before plotting. This will return `0` for the correlations lower than `0.5`.

Then we can use color mapping to show the rows with 0 as `not correlated`

```
corr3 = datasetcm.corr()
corr3 = corr3 [corr3 > 0.5].fillna(0)

corr3.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm', axis=None).set_precision(2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Erfan, thanks for the reply. Thi still leaves me with two many variable visible on the heatmap, and very hard to make out. Im looking to delete the non relevent variables from the heatmap

Comment: How do you see that for yourself? So if it has _any_ correlations < 0.5 you want to remove it? Because it will probably always have some variables with which it has > 0.5 correlation.

Comment: Yes i get what youre saying. I think a table format will be a better option. Thanks for your help